# Does BackgroundWorker's OnDoWork get called from the calling thread or the worker thread?

Tags: c#, .net, multithreading, winforms, backgroundworker

I have inherited a `BackgroundWorker` and overriden OnDoWork:

```
protected override void OnDoWork(DoWorkEventArgs e)
{
    WorkerEndedEvent.Reset();
    base.OnDoWork(e);
}
```

My question is, which thread will this be called from? Is it guaranteed to be called during my call to `RunWorkerAsync()` or may it be called afterwards (i.e. from the worker thread)?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It will be called by a worker thread and is not guaranteed to be called during call to `RunWorkerAsync`.

The documentation for [RunWorkerAsync](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/h01xszh2.aspx) states:

> The RunWorkerAsync method submits a request to start the operation
>   running asynchronously. When the request is serviced, the DoWork event
>   is raised, which in turn starts execution of your background
>   operation.

So `RunWorkerAsync` only submits a request to start the operation - which will raise the `DoWork` event.  It makes no guarantees about when `DoWork` will be called.

It also is [documented](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/System.ComponentModel.BackgroundWorker.aspx) as using a separate thread for it's work:

> Executes an operation on a separate thread.

So clearly DoWork is called on a different thread than `RunWorkerAsync` is called.

Comment: Great, thanks. Is that just from experience, or do you know of a documented explanation (MSDN appeared to say nothing about it!!)?

Comment: @noelicus It *has* to be called from a separate thread - otherwise it wouldn't be asynchronous!

Comment: @noelicus: [The documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.backgroundworker.aspx) contains an indirect hint: *"You must be careful not to manipulate any user-interface objects in your DoWork event handler. Instead, communicate to the user interface through the ProgressChanged and RunWorkerCompleted events"*. That means that DoWork is executed on a different thread than the one that called `RunWorkerAsync` but `ProgressChanged` and `RunWorkerCompleted` are marshaled back to the calling thread.

Comment: @MatthewWatson Doesn't that depend what is asynchronous? I've always assumed it simply meant the DoWork is about to be run "asynchronously". In fact it will *have* to call some stuff synchronously to get it going!!

Comment: @DanielHilgarth I know that! But the `OnDoWork` is not the same as `DoWork` and is not necessarily part of the `DoWork` call/thread.

Comment: @noelicus: Indeed, you are correct. `base.OnDoWork` *could* actually be the place that starts the background thread. Using ILSpy to peek into the source code however shows that this is not the case. `RunWorkerAsync` is what starts the background thread. That thread in turn calls `OnDoWork`.